# Specific versus general in titles of papers

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing, math-communication

It may not be possible to use mathoverflow in the way I'm hoping to, but my question is this:

**Should the title of a research paper in mathematics be as accurate and specific as possible (at the cost of it being pithy and easy-to-read)?**

The thing I have in mind is that many papers will do something like this: In the paper they study objects, call them "*Shmalgebras*". The main theorem is:

> Main Theorem of Paper: If $x$ is a *shmalgebra* satisfying assumption $P$, then it is
>   *regular*.

But the *title* will say something like

> Title of Paper: "Regularity results for shmalgebras".

And even worse is when the authors know full well there is a big famous conjecture along the lines of "all shmalgebras are regular". So since I am interested in the conjecture, I pretty much have to open the paper and read the abstract or part of the introduction to try to work out how close they have gotten to the conjecture. But sometimes it really feels like the math version of clickbait (for example, the assumption $P$ is very strong or specific and so the results are much narrower than the straightforward title might suggest). The authors have obviously avoided explaining assumption $P$ of their main theorem in full in the title: Presumably that can sometimes that can be too cumbersome, even if it is more informative? e.g.

> "Regularity results for shmalgebras which are quotients of balgebras and such that every derivative of the first coordinate of
>   the mapping function admits a finite covering by tuples".

But probably the authors don't want to just hint cryptically at a further condition because maybe this looks worse, e.g.

> "Regularity results for a class of shmalgebras satisfying a condition on the
>   mapping function"

**Does the community have any largely or even somewhat agreed upon ideas about what is best practice?**

Comment: Given that all three sorts of titles are quite common, I think it's safe to say that there is no agreement as to what is best :-)

Comment: By the way, when you want to italicize text on this site, it is better to enclose it in `*` (`*like this*`) instead of using math mode.  I made some edits, and also tried to make the spelling of "shmalgebra" consistent :-)

Comment: I don't the false modesty fashion from the 60's of writing titles looking like "*Some remarks on number theory*" and providing a small amount of useful information. In the same spirit (although maybe not attributable to fake modesty) titles such as "*On a theorem of Wu*" are not very useful (MSN counts 2300 occurrences of titles including "on a theorem of", although some include more information).

Comment: ‘Regularity results for some shmalgebras’? Or ‘many’, or ‘almost all’ if true? I don’t see the point of trying to convey a complicated condition in the title, that’s what the abstract is for.